Unity New Input System - when is it not experimental?
I am curious which version of unity until the New Input System is not listed as experimental?

Unity's Input System is a package, not a part of Unity's core engine.  That means that v1.0 of the Input System is the first production version.  It is not tied to any particular version of Unity, so any version of Unity that supports the Input System will suffice.

well the issue is that in the build, it always says New Input System (experimental)
